# Quick Websocket communication in Android

Tags: android, websocket, real-time

I'm trying to make an application for android such that I can control my computer mouse by moving on the phone screen. This means it needs to be quick and responsive.

So far I have the websocket server written that listens for movement, which works great when using a laptop's browser as the websocket client. However, I've tried several websocket clients for android, but they're all very slow and unresponsive.

Is it possible to create a websocket connection with android that can deliver real time communication? How? If not, any alternative solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is fastest streamed data, with chance of missing some packets - as they are not mandatory to have persistent state.

So in your case UDP transport protocol would be the best choice. As it offers speed in a price of reliability on data delivery. So you might have messages dropped, but the ones that will be delivered will get there relatively fast (most will be delivered).

As well you need to implement some extrapolation, in order to predict mouse movements if you want to have feeling of being "in same time" on both sides.

Although, clicking - should be delivered reliably, with specific location of click. That way clicks can be properly simulated.

Comment: I guess one of my questions is why do websockets perform so significantly worse on Android? Is it a limitation of the OS/hardware?Or is there potential for them to perform better?Is there reason to believe that a UDP implementation would perform so much better knowing that websocket performs so poorly?

Comment: First of all you need to find where is the bottleneck. Is there is big difference when you try to control mouse through WS through 3G, or when you are connected to WiFi? If difference is huge, then it is just poor latency.
You should expect 3G to give you 200-500 ms delay and is very "noisy".